# Cache\Session em Python

Tags: python, session, cookies

Eu tenho um *script* em Python que executa uma aplicação do Tornado. Dentro do `onmessage` eu tenho varias variáveis que vão manter um valor igual sempre, por isso não existe a necessidade de preenchê-las sempre que chegar uma mensagem nova para o Tornado.

Atualmente eu faço da seguinte maneira: salvo a variável como global e defino um valor a ela; dessa maneira como o *script* está sempre rodando, o valor persiste.

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma biblioteca que gere um *cookie* ou uma sessão para eu poder salvar essas variáveis.

Segue um exemplo de como está o código agora:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

var1 = ""
def teste():
    global var1
    if var1 == "":
        var 1 = "texto que vai persistir"
    print var1
    return var1

class WSMesa(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def open(self):
        print 'new connection'
    def on_message(self, message):
        retorno = teste()
        self.write_message(retorno)
    def on_close(self):
        print 'connection closed'
    def check_origin(self, origin):
        return True

application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r'/mesa', WSMesa)
])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application)
    http_server.listen(9999)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Comment: A ideia seria armazenar esses valores em cookie? Mas o processo de ler o cookie não será mais custoso que definir o valor da própria variável? Se elas não variam, você pode definí-las como *constantes*, tanto no escopo global, se fizer sentido para isso, ou no escopo da classe, como atributos de classe. Será mais fácil entender o que quer fazer se você [edit] a pergunta e adicionar esse trecho de código.

Comment: Coloquei um código de exemplo aonde eu preciso de que apenas se dê o valor a "var1" uma vez, claro que é só um exemplo mas a logica é completamente a mesma... Do jeito que esta funciona bem porém eu não acho que seja a maneira mais elegante de se fazer (sei lá to achando bem gambiarra isso)

Answer (score 0):

Por que você não armazena na própria classe, assim você conseguirá usar um atributo que pode ser visto entre todas as instâncias da mesma classe.

```
class WSMesa(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    var1 = 'word' # atributo de classe

    def open(self):
        print 'new connection'

    def on_message(self, message):
        retorno = self.var1 #acessa atributo de classe
        self.write_message(retorno)

    def on_close(self):
        print 'connection closed'

    def check_origin(self, origin):
        return True
```

E todo restante continua, somente abone a função teste e a variável global var1